# Rules replacement pattern for image type field

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I am using `Rules` and `HTML mail` module to send HTML email on various events. It is working fine, but I am getting problem in rendering image field(ie image) in email template.

I have field `field:cover-photo` which is of type image. This field appears under 
 `Replacement Pattern` token section. But when I include it, in the email it shows

```
Property field_cover_photo
```

and not the image. Any idea how can I show image in email.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution as follows:

To get the proper selector I switched to `Data Selection` mode.Then through hierarchy I got proper sector as `[comment:node:field-photo:file:url]`, which is URL of image. By using `img` tag, I am able to display image.

Comment: Beat me to it :)